# how to check if an object exists in the database and then insert it into a form in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have the following model:`models.py`

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
serial_number = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
make = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
model = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
color= models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
date_acquired = models.DateTimeField(auto_created=True)
acquired_from = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=ACQUIRED_FROM)
holder = models.ForeignKey(CertificateHolder, blank=False,)
dealer_license = models.ForeignKey(Dealer, blank=False)
```

I have created a form using `ModelForm` like this:

```
class IssueItemForm(ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = IssuedItem
    fields = '__all__'
```

A dealer needs to check if a certificate Holder exists before issuing the item, My code for that looks like this;

```
views.py:

def search(request):
try:
    query = request.GET.get('q')
    results = 0

except ValueError:
    query = None
    results = None
if query:
    results = CertificateHolder.objects.get(cert_no=query)

context = RequestContext(request)

return render_to_response('core/results.html', {"results": results, }, context_instance=context)
```

Then I have templates `search.html` and `results.html`

```
<form method="get" action="/search/">
<input type="text" name="q" id="id_q" value="{{ query }}"/>
<input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

In results.html I have

```
{% if results %}
<h3>The Certificate number is valid</h3>
<h3>To issues an item click the button below</h3>
<a href="{% url 'issueitem' %}">Issue A New Item</a>

{% else %}
<h3 class='error'>Please enter a valid Certificate</h3>
<form method="get" action="/search/">
  <input type="text" name="q" id="id_q" value="{{ query }}"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>

{% endif %}
```

The code works if there is a certificate in the database but if there is no match it throws an error like this:

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFkmW.png)

However I would like the error to be part of the code to tell the dealer that that number does not exist and that he should try another. Also when a certificate exists I would like it to be inserted into the holder field instead of fetching from the database like it is doing now. Where am i going wrong?

Comment: You can handle that error there and return render to response to some html page which says that try another dealer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also have to catch the `DoesNotExist` error. Change the `if query` to a try except block:

```
try:
    result = CertificateHolder.objects.get(cert_no=query)
except DoesNotExist:
    pass
```

Comment: I used  `ObjectDoesNotExist` exception n now it is working well.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use the [Django validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/validation/) and try to access the database from the 'clean' method the way @ilse2005 referred to . if you got DoesNotExist exception you have to raise an error in the form itself and handle it in your template.

Comment: Could you change link, because link is dead? Thank you